# Connection timed out Laravel-echo-server

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo

I know and I have seen this question

[Getting ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT Laravel echo server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57052488/getting-err-connection-timed-out-laravel-echo-server)

But I tried the solution in comment but it doesn't work.

I have my Laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
   "authHost": "https://mysite.it",
   "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
   "clients": [],
   "database": "redis",
   "databaseConfig": {
   "redis": {
      "host":"0.0.0.0",
      "port":"6379",
      "password": "mypwd"
   },
   "sqlite": {
      "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
  },
   "devMode": true,
   "host": null,
   "port": "6001",
   "protocol": "https",
   "socketio": {},
   "secureOptions": 67108864,
   "sslCertPath": "path_cert" ,
   "sslKeyPath": "path_key" ,
   "sslCertChainPath": "",
   "sslPassphrase": "",
   "subscribers": {
      "http": true,
      "redis": true
   },
   "apiOriginAllow": {
   "allowCors": true,
   "allowOrigin": "*",
   "allowMethods": "GET, PoST",
   "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested -With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-IdOrigin, Content-Type, X-A uth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-IdOri gin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF -TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
   }
}
```

And I have in my bootstrapjs the connection with Frontend:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
window.io = require('socket.io-client')
export var echo_instance = new Echo({
   broadcaster: 'socket.io',
   host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
   auth: {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token')
      }
   }
})
Vue.prototype.$echo = echo_instance
export default Vue
```

I have check if the port was closed but with netstat -an I can see:

> tcp6 0 0 :::6001 :::* LISTEN

But when I try to launch my app i receive:

> app.js:569 GET
> https://mysite.it:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NKoWZoK
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

How can I use the laravel echo with https protocol?

Comment: Better to setup your server in such a way that the echo communication is on port 443, and let your server decide if it's a standard or websockets request. In case of websockets, forward to echo server. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866032/configuring-apache-reverse-proxy-for-hosting-laravel-echo-server-on-production/56934080#56934080

Answer (score 0):

this might be because you have the wrong access token(dynamically added). why don't you try using a static access token first (copy the access token and paste it instead of localStorage.getItem('token')) for the user and see if it works.

Also try putting the following in laravel-echo-server.json file

> "allowOrigin": "http://mysite.it:80"

And, see if APP_URL is different in .env file

Comment: In allowOrigin I put "*", and the access static is not a problem, because, if that was the problem, i should receive a 403 and not a timeout

Comment: I have same issue, please check screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/amODu.png

Answer (score 0):

in `laravel-echo-server.json` you have a section named `socketio` that you can put your socketio settings here.

```
{
  "sid": "FSDjX-WRwSA4zTZMALqx",
  "upgrades": ["websocket"],
  "pingInterval": 25000,
  "pingTimeout": 20000
}
```

according to socketio documentation ([Handshake](https://socket.io/docs/v4/how-it-works/#handshake) and [pingTimeout](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#pingtimeout)) there is an option named `pingTimeout` and default timeout is set to 20000 ms.
you can increase timeout time according to the needs of the project.